# Check the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \big( \frac{1}{\log n} + \frac{\cos n}{n^2} \big)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n \big( \frac{1}{\log n} + \frac{\cos n}{n^2} \big)$.

Any hint, from where to start. I'm completely stuck here. None of the known convergence test is working for me. Any help on to deal with please??

**Edit :** In the original question the index $n$ started from $1$.

Comment: I think the lower index of summation should be $2$; $1/\ln(1)$ is an undefined expression.

Comment: Yes I also agree, even I'll change it but the thing is that I got the problem exactly as I've posted here.

Comment: As a general rule, if you have a series of the form $$\sum (a_n + b_n)$$ then first look at the two separate series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$.  If both converge, then great, the original series converges.  If one converges and the other diverges, then great, the original series diverges.  If both diverge?  Then you have to look deeper at the problem, because it could diverge or it could converge.

Comment: @Brian I completely forgot to look at it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}+\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}+(-1)^n\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right)$$

The series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}$$

is convergent by the alternating series test; $1/\ln(n)$ is strictly decreasing and tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. The series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}$$

is absolutely convergent because

$$\left|(-1)^n\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right|=\frac{\left|(-1)^n\right| |\cos(n)|}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

and $\displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ is a convergent $p$-series. It follows that the sum of these two series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{\ln(n)}+(-1)^n\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{\ln(n)}+\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}\right)$$

is convergent.

Comment: What was that...!!! I didn't see it as a sum of two convergent series. It was so evident, I feel so dumb. :(